# Realistic for intelligent undergrad to build low cost muon scatter detector?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, astrophysics, electrical-engineering

With a budget of under $2000USD, would it be possible for an undergrad student to build a muon scatter detector (drift tubes or another method)?

Answer (score 3):

[This paper on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.01196) seems to be exactly what you're looking for, so the answer appears to be a resounding yes.

The design uses an inexpensive plastic scintillator and a silicon photomultiplier for light collection, and the total cost per detector is claimed to be around $100 which, as far as I can tell, is very plausible.

That being said, the detector itself is not the only thing you'd need.  At the very least, you'd need the electronics necessary to read the detector output and some software (which you could probably write by yourself) to interpret those readings. You'd also need to calibrate the thing, which might take additional resources unless you have ready access to well-characterized radioactive sources.  This would take a bit of extra money, but I can't imagine it'd be even close to your stated budget of $2000.

Comment: This is for just a detector, but the question was geared towards scatter detection, which is a little more involved.  Please correct me if your answer includes scatter detection.

Comment: @JaDi I'm not familiar with that terminology.  Can you describe what you'd like to use the detector for so I get a better idea?

Comment: @JaDi - Exactly what do you want to do? Does the detector have to be a "scatter detector", which I have no idea what it is but from your question I assume is related to a drift chamber in construction. How about a cloud chamber? If you just want to see muon tracks, they apparently work well. ( https://www.exploratorium.edu/exhibits/cloud-chamber ).

Comment: It is worth noting that the each of  the things mentioned in the second paragraph (readout electronics; analysis software; and characterization and calibration) is generally as large a problem as the physical build.

Comment: @dmckee I definitely agree. A large part of my research work as an undergrad was to calibrate our brand new $4\pi$ NaI detector and it was no joke!

Comment: @SamuelWeir I was indeed referring to mapping muon vectors, as it is desirable to map inbound and outbound vectors, with a high density object between, to determine scatter.

Comment: @JaDi It sounds like you are trying to assess the shielding capabilities of the "high density object," in which case you need only measure the muon flux separately on either side of the object.  Immersing the object in a cloud chamber as Samuel suggests could give you a more qualitative idea of what's going on.

Comment: @J.Murray I was leaning more towards rudimentary muon tomography.  Scattering would be a good way to passively detect high density objects.  I’ll do reading into cloud chambers and hope this stays open in the meantime.  I am familiar with resistive plate chambers but these seem cost prohibitive for an undergraduate, unless individuals here can provide a cost effective method for construction....

Comment: @JaDi What you want is a detector that is both position and direction sensitive. The detector in the linked paper is only position sensitive at the level of *"well, it hit the scintillator"* and has no significant direction sensitivity. The naive answer is to use many small and simple detectors set in a known geometry, but that drives the price up. A common solution in the last 15-20 years has been scintillating fiber and a multiple SiPM-on a chip module (last time I looked 4x4, 8x4, 8x8 configurations were most common. For 2D position sensitivity you use crossed planes.

Comment: But price is going to be a problem. Worse, the linked paper only got down to US$100/detector by buying their SiPMs in bulk (and probably producing PCBs in non-trivial numbers, too).

Comment: Some seem to use alternating x-y arrays of drift tubes, but again, this does seem cost prohibitive as well.

Comment: @dmckee Do you have any white papers on the use of scintillating fiber (assuming you’re referring to the wire in a drift tube) and SiPM?  I’ve found affordable 4x4 config SiPM but would like to learn more in deployment of them in this context.

Comment: @JaDi Scintillating fiber is an optical fiber (usually polymer) doped with scintillating agents. It servers as both detector and light guide. Last time I looked at any (ten years ago!) diameters were typically usual $1$–$3\,\mathrm{mm}$.  Which leads to good resolution, but it takes a *lot* of fibers to instrument any significant area. They are used just like any other hodoscopes, only they are flexible and compact.